# How can I reduce SQL Query complexity and length in RShiny App?

Tags: sql, r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am building an app using RShiny which queries a SQLite database.
I have finished writing the code for the app, but I am having trouble reducing the complexity of the query / using glue_sql function. As it is right now there are many OR statements which I believe might be slowing the query down.
I used sqlInterpolate to conduct the query to prevent any SQL injections, as this is what is cited on the RShiny website as what should be done.

This is my code as of right now:

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
titlePanel("Application"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Assay", label = "Assay Type:", choices = c("MBP1","EV","Oxidation","WGAS","WLS","Genomics"),
selected = c("MBP1","EV","Oxidation","WGAS","WLS","Genomics")), #Assay
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Vendor", label = "Vendor:", choices = c("AKE","BSA"),
selected = c("AKE","BSA")), #Vendor
actionButton("read", "Read From Database"),
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Study",
                    label = "Study Type",
                    choices = c("MP", "CSP"),
selected = c("MP", "CSP")),
dateRangeInput(inputId = "Date", label = "Sample Date Range:", format ="yyyy-mm-dd"), #Date
actionButton("read", "Read From Database")),
        mainPanel(h1("Sample Count:"),
 dataTableOutput("Samples_Sorted_by_Study"),
 dataTableOutput("Samples_Sorted_by_Assay_and_Vendor")) #table
    ) #closing navbarPage
) #closing fluidPage UI
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output){
    #Storing values in myData variable
    myData <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(
        input$read,
        {
            myData$assay <- input$Assay
            myData$vendor <- input$Vendor
            myData$date_val <- input$Date
            myData$studytype <- input$Study

            #Opening database connection
            connectiontodb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "example.sqlite")

            #Shortening Query??
            #myData$study_int <- c(myData$studytype[1], myData$studytype[2])
            #myData$study_int <- glue_sql("{myData$study_int*}")
            
            #conducting first query of samples grouped by study 
            #Sample query of example.sqlite database

            myData$interpolatequery1 <- sqlInterpolate(connectiontodb,
            "Select study, count(genomic_id), count(specimen_id)
            FROM exampletable WHERE study = ?studytype1 OR study = ?studytype2
            GROUP BY study", 
            studytype1 = myData$studytype[1], studytype2 = myData$studytype[2])

            myData$exampledataSQLQuery1 <- dbGetQuery(connectiontodb, myData$interpolatequery1)

            #Closing connection to database
            dbDisconnect(connectiontodb)
  
            #Correcting Column Names
            colnames(myData$exampledataSQLQuery1) <- c("Study", "Genomic Id", "Specimen Id")     
 }
    )
    
    output$Samples_Sorted_by_Study <- renderDataTable(myData$exampleSQLQuery1)
    

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I condense the query so that there isn't a need for so many OR statements, but also protect against SQL injection?

Comment: Your query needs a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You are right thank you for the reminder, it is in my code in RStudio made a mistake when re-writing it for this post.

Comment: you can replace ORs with `IN` in your were statement:  `WHERE study IN (?studytype1 , ?studytype2 , ... )`